# C# Declaring class type in list object is not using default parameter value?

Tags: c#

When the Orders class is getting initialized, the default constructor in order gets called but Initialized has a false value instead of true even though no parameter is passed. I seem to not understand this behavior at all.

```
public class Orders
{
    [JsonProperty("Objects")]
    public List<Order> Items { get; set; } = new List<Order>();
}

public class Order
{
    public Order(bool _initialize = true)
    {
        if (_initialize)
        {
            this.Cr = 0;
            this.User = Guid.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The construct method work https://dotnetfiddle.net/ucS3RA

Comment: issue comes when deserializing from NewtonSoft

Comment: [FYI](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConstructorAttribute.htm)

Answer (score 1):

The default constructor of `Order` does **not** get called when `Orders.Items` is initiazed. Only an empty list is created.

Also  `Order(bool _initialize = true)` is not the default constructor because it has one argument specified (even though it is optional).

To create this functionality and define a default constructor you need two definitions

```
public Order()
{
    // default values
}

public Order(bool _initialize) : this()
{
    if (_initialize)
    {
        // specific values
        this.Cr = 0;
        this.User = Guid.Empty;
    }
}
```